# how to resize the button image in iphone

Tags: iphone

im new in iphone.now im developing button images in iphone. here images are view like large size view. I want to resize the image.I implement code like this.

```
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bearlarge.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bufflo_large.jpg"]];
 [images addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"camel_large.jpg"]];
 UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

 int row = 0;
 int column = 0;


 for(int i = 0; i < images.count; ++i) {



 // UIImage *thumb = [images objectAtIndex:i];

  UIButton * button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];



   button.frame = CGRectMake(column*105+14, row*105+10, 50,50);


  [button setImage:[images objectAtIndex:i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  [button addTarget:self 
       action:@selector(buttonClicked:) 
   forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  button.tag = i; 




  [view addSubview:button];

  if (column == 2) {
   column = 0;
   row++;
  } else {
   column++;
  }
   }
 //[view setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, (row+1) * 80 + 10)];
    self.view = view;
 [view release];
```

can any one plz send me code for resize the images in iphone.

Thankyou in advance.